# What do I need to trigger 2 external flash units from a D5100?

Tags: off-camera-flash, nikon-d5100, manual-flash, triggers

I'd like to connect 2 [Yongnuo i-TTL Speedlite Flash units](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007E3PSGW) to a [Nikon D5100](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004V4IWKG). I'm fine with a wired connection. I only want to operate the flash units in manual mode. I do not want to use the camera's flash.

What cables would I need? Would I need some sort of splitter?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to use the flashes in manual mode, I recommend [radio triggers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005IQRMN4). You can pick up a set with one transmitter and two receivers for around $30USD. I use this set occasionally. If I needed them on a daily basis I would invest in something a little heavier duty, but these have never failed to fire, and are fairly easy on the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest triggering one of the flashes through a wired connection, and putting the other flash in optical slave mode (so it's triggered by the first flash firing).

You need

- a [flash shoe to PC adapter](https://www.google.no/search?q=flash+hot+shoe+to+pc+adapter&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=NsCeUfinH82O4gSgzoDADg&ved=0CGEQsAQ&biw=1192&bih=683). ("PC" is unrelated to personal computers, it's a [standard for flash connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prontor-Compur))
- a PC cable of the required length.